# Beginner refactor question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know the best or most correct way to refactor this.

```
series = Hash.new
series[:series_id] = doc.xpath("Data/Series/id").inner_text if not doc.xpath("Data/Series/id").nil?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
series = { :series_id => doc.xpath("Data/Series/id").try(:inner_text) }
```

Comment: DigitalRoss is correct, exactly what I was going to put. The `try` function works wonders.

Comment: This is a nice one. While it behaves slightly different: it will always add the `:series` key. The effect is in most cases the same. `series[:series_id]` will also return `nil` if the key is not defined, unless somewhere they explicitly test for the existence of the key.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
series = Hash.new
id_element = doc.xpath("Data/Series/id")
series[:series_id] =  id_element.inner_text unless id_element.nil?
```

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "if id_element" on the last line instead of "unless id_element.nil?"

Answer (score 0):

I think the most revolutionary refactoring would be using xml to object mapping library like [happymapper](https://github.com/jnunemaker/happymapper) and leave all this dirty implementation details under the hood.